# Oracle SQL - Max from Group by with limit

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I have the following data:

```
Table: CROSS_REF
DEPT LOC TRAN
100  A1   10
100  A2   10
100  A3   20
```

the max count of Tran 20 is 1 and Tran 10 is 2.

I Need to return this data:

```
TRAN
10
```

how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

From Oracle 12c, you can use:

```
SELECT tran
FROM   cross_ref
GROUP BY tran
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cross_ref(DEPT, LOC, TRAN) AS
SELECT 100, 'A1', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 'A2', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 'A3', 20 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | TRAN |
> | --- |
> | 10 |

---

If you could have multiple rows with the highest count and you want them all then:

```sql
SELECT tran
FROM   cross_ref
GROUP BY tran
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

---

Before Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT tran
FROM   (
  SELECT tran
  FROM   cross_ref
  GROUP BY tran
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

or, if you want ties:

```sql
SELECT tran
FROM   (
  SELECT tran,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rnk
  FROM   cross_ref
  GROUP BY tran
)
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4ebd4732f2bb7fc36e0a27a36294af5d)*

Answer (score 0):

The value that you are looking for is called the *mode* in statistics, and Oracle has a function [`stats_mode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions154.htm) to calculate this.  Assuming that you want the value per department:

```
SELECT dept, stats_mode(tran)
FROM cross_ref
GROUP BY dept;
```

If you want the overall mode:

```
SELECT stats_mode(tran)
FROM cross_ref;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=df105e886290e29a01fdaa47ab3d2c90) is a db<>fiddle.